# ACPI BIOS Error (Bug): Failure creating named object

Tags: boot, usb, 20.04, acpi

I'm trying to launch a live from a USB of Ubuntu 20.04 but I get the next errors

[Errors while trying to start Ubuntu from USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCSNq.jpg)

The laptop has a M2 device with Windows 10, but after an update doesn't startup. Only shows the HP's logo and after the screen turn black.

Windows doesn't start, so I can't resume and shutdown Windows fully.

I tried to start Windows recovery mode, but nothing happens, just the logo and then the screen turn black.

Also I ran a test of SSD/M2 and get Check of Short DST: Failed.

[Check of short DST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeMd8.jpg)

I have consulted and everything points to the need to replace the storage device.

I want to know if this is really necessary and if there is any way that I can start Ubuntu from Live either to install it or use it to rescue the data that is on the laptop.

Comment: Did you ever get further with this? I just tried live USB booting 20.04 and 20.10 on an ASUS Zephyrus G14 with Ryzen 5900HS and got a similar error. I'm just starting to troubleshoot now.